# Возврат на предидущую страницу javascript

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Нужно реализовать возврат на предидущую страницу с учетом позиции скрола пользователя.

пытался делать так:

```
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
```

В браузере Chrome работает и перенаправление на страницу и на позицию прокрутки, но позиция прокрутки страницы работает через раз.
В браузере Mozilla не работает сохранение скрола пользователя и по этому просто перенаправляет на страницу.

Я хочу записывать состояние скрола пользователя в локалСторедж и в случае если он хочет вернуться на страницу сразу отображать ему позицию на которой он был.

Comment: а если вернется на 2 страницы назад?

Comment: Вот мне кажется это путь в никуда. Вам в стораже нужно будет сохранять все состояния на каждом переходе. Потом учитывать их во время загрузки каждой страницы .....

Comment: Я внес поправки в вопрос, точнее в код

Comment: Да не вопрос сохраняйте. В чем проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том что, редирект на предидущую страницу работает, но отображает страницу не на той позиции на которой был юзер, а мне нужно чтоб перебрасывало назад с позицией на которой он был.

Comment: Например:
Он был на Главной долистал до Футера, перешел в блок, долистал до карусели, Нажал кнопку вернуться и его перебросило на Главную и отобразило не шапку а Футер